# finding the minimum value of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

let $f$ be a function of three variables s.t
$$f(X)=(X-A)^2+(X-B)^2+(X-C)^2$$
Where $X=(x,y,z)$, and those three vectors are distincs $$\cases{A=(a_1,a_2,a_3) \\ B=(b_1,b_2,b_3) \\ C=(c_1,c_2,c_3)}$$

Find the minimum and the maximum value of this function.

Since this question was in *Lagrange Multipliers's* section, I thought that using it is sufficient to solve the problem, but it doesn't work.
$$f(x,y,z)=(x-a_1,y-a_2,z-a_3)^2+(x-b_1,y-b_2,z-b_3)^2+(x-c_1,y-c_2,z-c_3)^2$$
$$=(x-a_1)^2+(y-a_2)^2+(z-a_3)^2+(x-b_1)^2+(y-b_2)^2+(z-b_3)^2$$
$$+(x-c_1)^2+(y-c_2)^2+(z-c_3)^2$$

Comment: How can we answer your question when you don't specify what exactly is not working for you? And what do you mean by the square of a vector?

Comment: squaring a vector is just dotting it with itself. @ShubhamJohri

Comment: Maximum does not exist, you can make $x_1$ as large as possible unless you missed a constraint. I don't see why Lagrange is needed for minimization. The objective function can be separated into $g_1(x)+g_2(y)+g_3(z)$ so we can simply individually minimize $g_1,g_2,g_3$ using derivatives.

Comment: 'using derivatives' do you mean $\nabla g_1=0$ @ShubhamJohri

Comment: Yes, $g_1(x)=(x-a_1)^2+(x-b_1)^2+(x-c_1)^2$ can be minimized by derivatives or completing the square method

Comment: but sometimes the critical point aren't the minima or maxima of the function, so how can i check that this is the actual minimum of the function @ShubhamJohri

Comment: If the first derivative is negative for $x<x^*$ and positive for $x>x^*$, then $x^*$ is the global minimum. Alternatively recall that $g_1(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial with a positive coefficient $3$ of $x^2$, so it is represented by an upward opening parabola which attains global minimum at its only stationary point. Alternatively, if you are familiar with convex functions, you would know that $g_1(x)$ is convex and any local minimum is a global minimum. Alternatively just complete the square...$g_1(x)=(x-(a_1+b_1+c_1))^2+a_1^2+b_1^2+c_1^2-(a_1+b_1+c_1)^2$ so $g_1(x)$ is minimized when...?

Comment: when $x=0$? we get $g_1(x)=a_1^2+b_1^2+c_1^2$ ? @ShubhamJohri

Comment: I think I messed up the previous expression of $g_1(x)$, which should actually be $g_1(x)=\left(\sqrt3x-\frac1{\sqrt3}(a_1+b_1+c_1)\right)^2+a_1^2+b_1^2+c_1^2-(a_1+b_1+c_1)^2/3$. Now, the first term containing $x$ is always non-negative. We can only make it as small as zero, in which case we get $\sqrt3x=(a_1+b_1+c_1)/\sqrt3$ and $g_1(x)_\min=a_1^2+b_1^2+c_1^2-(a_1+b_1+c_1)^2/3$

Answer (score 1):

Define column vectors (all in lower cases) to be the transpose of its upper case counter parts:

$$x=X^t, a=A^t, b=B^t, c=C^t$$
Define inner product $(a, b)$ = sum ($j=1$ to $3$) {$a_j*b_j$}

where $a_j$, $b_j$ are $j^{th}$ components of $a$ and $b$ respectively and $j=1,2, 3$. We have scalar function of three variables: $f(x)= (x-a, x-a)+ (x-b, x-b) +(x-c, x-c)$

The critical point $x^*$ is obtained by differentiate f (.) wrt x (aka gradient) and set it equal to zero. Hence we get its derivative $\frac{df}{dx} (x^*) = 0$  which implies $2 [(x^*-a)+ (x^*-b) + (x^*-c) ] = 0$  or $x^* = \frac{(a+b+c)}{3}$

We know $f$ has a minimum at $x^*$ because its Hessian matrix $H = \text{diag}[d_1, d_2, d_3]$ is positive definite.  The min value of $f$ is given by

$$f(x*) = \frac{2}{3}[||a||^2 +||b||^2 +||c||^2] -\frac{2}{3} [(a,b)+(b,c)+(c,a)]$$

$$= \frac{2}{3}{ (a, a)+(b, b)+(c,c)- [(a,b)+(b,c)+(c,a)]}$$

Comment: You are MSE user since 4yrs $\implies$ use MathJax for your posts please!

Comment: For instance, nice norms are obtained by "\|" .